# Sorting and organizing DNS records

Tags: python, dns

So I have a fairly simple set of data, such as:
`['test.sh','api.test.sh','blah.api.test.sh','test.com','api.test.com']`

and I need to transform into a hierarchical data structure, I was thinking of doing it with a dictionary:

```
{ 'name':'test.sh',
  'children': { 'name':'api.test.sh',
                'children': { 'name':'blah.api.test.sh' }
              }
},
{
  'name':'test.com',
  'children': { 'name':'api.test.com' }
}
```

And essentially for each high level name I can work my way down and perform the operations I need to do.

My question has more to do with creating a simple way to sort, match, and transform the data. I can think of a few ways to do this but I can't think of anything quite elegant. Also I'm doing this in python.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this could be what you are looking for:

```
def sort_dns(l):


    to_return = []
    # Get top-level domains: the domains that contain the less amount of dots.
    count_list = [i.count('.') for i in l]
    min_dots = min(count_list)
    top_domains = [i for i in l if i.count('.') == min_dots]
    # Now for each domain, we find it subdomains.
    for domain in top_domains:
        sub_domains = [i for i in l if domain in i and i is not domain]
        #And untill we aren't at the deepest level, we continue looking for sub domains and repeat the structure
        sub_sub_domains = sort_dns(sub_domains) if not len(sub_domains) == 0 else None
        to_return.append({'name' : domain, 'childrens' : sub_sub_domains})

    return to_return
```

As you see this function call itself recursively to go infinitely "deep" if needed.

With your example, the result is the following

```
[
    {
        'name': 'test.sh',
        'childrens': [
            {
                'name': 'api.test.sh', 
                'childrens': [
                    {'name': 'blah.api.test.sh', 'childrens': None}
                ]
            }
         ]
    },
    {
        'name': 'test.com', 
        'childrens': [
            {'name': 'api.test.com', 'childrens': None}
        ]
    }
]
```

As you see it handle the case of multiple childrens and no children at all.

Note that if you don't want the `'childrens': None`, You can change the function to that:

```
def sort_dns(l):


    to_return = []
    # Get top-level domains: the domains that contain the less amount of dots.
    count_list = [i.count('.') for i in l]
    min_dots = min(count_list)
    top_domains = [i for i in l if i.count('.') == min_dots]
    # Now for each domain, we find it subdomains.
    for domain in top_domains:
        sub_domains = [i for i in l if domain in i and i is not domain]
        #And untill we aren't at the deepest level, we continue looking for sub domains and repeat the structure
        sub_sub_domains = sort_dns(sub_domains) if not len(sub_domains) == 0 else None
        if sub_sub_domains:
            to_return.append({'name' : domain, 'childrens' : sub_sub_domains})
        else:
            to_return.append({'name' : domain})

    return to_return
```

Note that this is Python3 Code.

EDIT: I've read roippi Answer and this works great too, His solution is surely the most pythonic. This one's advantage is that it doesn't require any imports. But you should really consider roippi answer as the most elegant.

Comment: Thanks! this looks pretty good, I actually came up with a similar method so it's nice to see that i'm not alone.

Answer (score 1):

So, I see a proper approach to this problem happening in three steps: **sort**, **group**, **format**.

First, **sort**ing your inputs to arrange them in logical groups.  You can define a quick helper function to define your sort key:

```
def sorter(netloc):
    split = netloc.split('.')
    return (split[::-1], -len(split))
```

And use it thusly:

```
data = ['test.sh','api.test.sh','blah.api.test.sh','test.com','api.test.com', 'another.com', 'sub.another.com', 'sub.sub.another.com']

#shuffling data, to show that sorting works
import random
random.shuffle(data)

sorted(data, key=sorter)
Out[14]: 
['another.com',
 'sub.another.com',
 'sub.sub.another.com',
 'test.com',
 'api.test.com',
 'test.sh',
 'api.test.sh',
 'blah.api.test.sh']
```

Now that everything's in the correct order, do a similar **group**ing operation with `itertools.groupby` which groups by the `blah.com` part of `x.y.z.blah.com`:

```
def grouper(netloc):
     return ''.join(netloc.split('.')[-2:])

#in-place sort, replicating sorted() call above
data.sort(key=sorter)

from itertools import groupby

[list(g) for k,g in groupby(data, grouper)]
Out[27]: 
[['another.com', 'sub.another.com', 'sub.sub.another.com'],
 ['test.com', 'api.test.com'],
 ['test.sh', 'api.test.sh', 'blah.api.test.sh']]
```

Lastly, you need to **format** these groups into your desired hierarchy.  Here is a quick-and-dirty implementation:

```
def make_hierarchy(groups):
     from copy import deepcopy
     _groups = deepcopy(groups)
     ret = []
     for li in _groups:
         current = {}
         ret.append(current)
         while li:
             current['name'] = li.pop()
             if li:
                 nxt = {}
                 current['children'] = nxt
                 current = nxt
     return ret

print(json.dumps(make_hierarchy(grouped), indent=2))
[
  {
    "children": {
      "children": {
        "name": "another.com"
      },
      "name": "sub.another.com"
    },
    "name": "sub.sub.another.com"
  },
  {
    "children": {
      "name": "test.com"
    },
    "name": "api.test.com"
  },
  {
    "children": {
      "children": {
        "name": "test.sh"
      },
      "name": "api.test.sh"
    },
    "name": "blah.api.test.sh"
  }
]
```

This last implementation depends on a couple of assumptions, namely that there will not be any equivalent-length netlocs in a given group, i.e. `sub1.example.com` and `sub2.example.com` will never happen.  Obviously you can tweak the implementation as needed.

Comment: Thanks! it's great seeing other people's implementations, great answer!